# etree.strip_tags returning 'None' when trying to strip tag

Tags: python, lxml

Script:

```
print entryDetails

for i in range(len(entryDetails)):
    print etree.tostring(entryDetails[i])

    print etree.strip_tags(entryDetails[i], 'entry-details')
```

Output:

```
[<Element entry-details at 0x234e0a8>, <Element entry-details at 0x234e878>]
<entry-details>2014-02-05 11:57:01</entry-details>
None
<entry-details>2014-02-05 12:11:05</entry-details>
None
```

How is etree.strip_tags failing to strip the entry-details tag? <del>Is the dash in the tag name affecting it?</del>

Comment: Why don't you try a few versions and try to get it to work? Or at least verify your hypothesis.

Comment: I tried a tag without a dash and it still returned 'None'. Updated original question.

Answer (score 1):

`strip_tags()` does not return anything. It strips off the tags in-place.

The [documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_tags) says: "*Note that this will not delete the element (or ElementTree root element) that you passed even if it matches. It will only treat its descendants.*".

Demo code:

```
from lxml import etree

XML = """
<root>
 <entry-details>ABC</entry-details>
</root>"""

root = etree.fromstring(XML)
ed = root.xpath("//entry-details")[0]
print ed
print

etree.strip_tags(ed, "entry-details")       # Has no effect 
print etree.tostring(root)
print

etree.strip_tags(root, "entry-details")     
print etree.tostring(root)
```

Output:

```
<Element entry-details at 0x2123b98>

<root>
 <entry-details>ABC</entry-details>
</root>

<root>
 ABC
</root>
```